# JMS connection kills websocket

Tags: javascript, jakarta-ee, websocket, jms

I have a website which opens a websocket and displays a message sent from the server in an alert. However, as soon as I create a JMS connection, the websocket won't connect anymore. The app runs on glassfish 4. This is the code:

wstest.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
  <h:head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <h:outputScript name="websocket.js" library="js" target="head"/>
  </h:head>
  <h:body>
    TODO
  </h:body>
</html>
```

websocket.js:

```
var host = 'ws://localhost:8095/path';
var websocket = new WebSocket(host);

websocket.onopen = function () {
  alert('Websocket open!');
};

websocket.onmessage = function (event) {
  alert(event.data);
};
```

WebsocketEndpoint.java:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/path")
public class WebsocketEndpoint {

  private WebsocketChat chat = new WebsocketChat();

  @OnOpen
  public void onOpen(Session session) {
    System.out.println("Session opened");
    session.getAsyncRemote().sendText("Hello Javascript");
  }
}
```

WebsocketChat.java:

```
public class WebsocketChat {

  @Resource(mappedName="jms/ConnectionFactory")
  private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

  public WebsocketChat() {
    //init();
  }

  public final void init() {
    try {
      Connection con = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    } catch (JMSException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(WebsocketChat.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the call to the init method in the constructor of WebsocketChat is commented. This way I can see both javascript alerts: 'Websocket open!' when the websocket is opened, and 'Hello Javascript', which comes from server. The message "Session opened" is also visible in the glassfish output.

However, when I uncomment the init method in the WebsocketChat constructor, I can still see the 'Websocket opened' alert, but the 'Hello Javascript' alert will not be displayed. The "Session opened" message also vanished from the glassfish output. The init method is responsible for creating the JMS connection.

Answer (score 1):

I expect that your `init()` method is throwing `NullPointerException` because `connectionFactory` will not have been initialised:

```
public class WebsocketChat {

    @Resource(mappedName="jms/ConnectionFactory")
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    public WebsocketChat() {
        // You can't access the connectionFactory here because the container cannot
        // inject it before the the object is created.
        // The object will not be created until this constructor has completed
        // executing.
    }

    /* The container will call this after the object is created */
    @PostConstruct
    public final void init() {
        try {
            try (Connection con = connectionFactory.createConnection()) {
                // do something with the connection...
            }
        } catch (JMSException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WebsocketChat.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Updated WebsocketEndpoint:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/path")
public class WebsocketEndpoint {

    /*
     * You need to inject this. The container will create and initialise it for you.
     */
    @Inject
    private WebsocketChat chat;

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        System.out.println("Session opened");
        session.getAsyncRemote().sendText("Hello Javascript");
    }
}
```

> FWIW, the above code works for me in WildFly 10.1 with one change:

```
    @Resource(lookup="java:/ConnectionFactory")  
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
```

which happens to be the default ConnectionFactory in WildFly.

Also, your JavaScript probably needs to include the webapp context in it's web socket URL:

```
 var host = 'ws://localhost:8095/<webapp-context>/path';
```

> The code above also works in GlassFish 4.1.1 with the following change:

```
    @Resource(name="java:comp/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory")  
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
```

Comment: What version of GlassFish are you using? Double check to make sure that you have not used `new` anywhere.

Comment: Although that sounds right, there was no NullPointerException. With your modifications however, init() isn't called at all, even after annotating `@Named` to the class. What do I have to do in order to get `@PostConstruct` working?

Comment: glassfish 4.1.1

Comment: The NPE was guaranteed. You just have not seen any evidence of it.

Comment: The `new` isn't there anymore.

Comment: How can that be? There is no NPE in the glassfish output.

Comment: `connectionFactory` is guaranteed to be null from within the constructor and it's call to `init()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139491/discussion-between-steve-c-and-user1785730).